# Putting files to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am running below commands on console:

```
[root@master ~]# pwd
/root
[root@master ~]# vi test.txt
#editting file
[root@master ~]# su - hdfs -c "hdfs dfs -put /root/test.txt /user/ambari-qa"
put: `/root/test.txt': No such file or directory
```

the file is there

```
[root@master ~]# pwd
/root
[root@master ~]# ls -l
total 9636984
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1823777034 Jun 12 08:34 ambari-2.6.2.2-centos6.tar.gz
-rw-------. 1 root root        716 Mar 19  2012 anaconda-ks.cfg
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root       4096 Oct 15 11:30 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root       4096 Oct 15 11:30 Documents
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root       4096 Oct 15 11:30 Downloads
-rw-r--r--  1 root root         15 Oct 18 20:16 enabled~
-rw-r--r--  1 root root         15 Oct 18 20:38 enablez~
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  511720220 Oct 15 19:33 HDP-2.6.5.0-centos6-rpm.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 7303095942 May 15 03:50 HDP-2.6.5.0-centos6-rpm.tar.gz.1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   43941068 Aug 13 20:28 HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.22-centos6.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  185646832 Oct 15 17:04 jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root       4096 Oct 15 11:30 Music
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root       4096 Oct 15 11:30 Pictures
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root      12148 Dec 16  2011 post-install
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root        552 Dec 16  2011 post-install.log
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root       4096 Oct 15 11:30 Public
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root       4096 Oct 15 11:30 Templates
-rw-r--r--  1 root root          2 Oct 23 05:39 test
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root          3 Oct 23 06:37 test.txt
```

However,I am getting no such file or directory, I am creating the file in the path but I get that error?

Comment: Did you check with `ls` command if file is there?

Comment: yes, it is there, I am using kerbros in my cluster as well..

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem was due to privilege at /root directory

```
dr-xr-x---.  25 root root  4096 Oct 23 06:37 root
```

using chmod 755 worked then